# Finding numbers in an array that are less than or equal to numbers in another array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

If given arr1[1, 2, 3] and arr2[2, 4] I need to find how many elements in arr1 are less than or equal to each element in arr2. For those arrays, the output should be [2, 3] because 2 elements in arr1 are less than or equal to arr2[1] and 3 elements in arr1 are less than or equal to arr2[2].

I've solved this problem in a naive way, but I'd like to get the runtime complexity down - this solution doesn't handle large arrays very well at all. Could anyone shed some light on how I could refactor this to reduce the complexity?

```js
counts([1, 2, 3] ,[2, 4])

function counts(nums, maxes) {
        let newArr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < maxes.length; i++){
            let count = 0;
            for(let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
                if(nums[j] <= maxes[i]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            newArr.push(count);
        }
        console.log(newArr);
    }
```

Comment: are the arrays sorted, at least the second one?

Comment: Doesn't matter, they could be sorted in O(n log n), still much better than the current O(n^2).

Comment: @NinaScholz I could sort the arrays, but I need the output to follow the same order/size as arr2. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by sorting the first array. Then, for each element in the second array, use binary search to find where it would be inserted into the first array (but do not actually insert it). This index will tell you how many elements in the first array are less than or equal to that element in the second array. Append that to your result array and continue. This has a complexity of O(n log n) with n being the size of the larger array.

```js
counts([1, 2, 3] ,[2, 4])

function counts(nums, maxes) {
    nums.sort();
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < maxes.length; i++){
        let index = binarySearch(maxes[i], nums);
        result.push(index);
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

I have not included here the code for `binarySearch`, but it would in O(log n) time find the index of the smallest item in `nums` greater than `maxes[i]`. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on binary search.

Comment: Ah this makes sense! I've never tried a binary search in JavaScript so I'll do some digging on how to do that, but this definitely sounds better.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should click the check to indicate it, so that it shows up as answered

Comment: Since `binarySearch` is not defined, don't put it as a code snippet for execution. Just put it inside a markup for code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res =  arr2.map(x => arr1.filter(elem => elem<=x).length);
```

Comment: A bit messy, my answer is clearer, but this would probably work as a clever one liner. Either that or you would suffer from an off-by-one error

Answer (score 0):

Look into binary search, basically you reduce your collection every step. [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method

```
const comapreArrays = (arr1,arr2) => {
 return arr1.map(numInFirstArray => arr2.filter(numInSecArray => 
  numInFirstArray <= numInSecArray).length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1=[1,5,3];
var arr2=[2,4];
var res = arr2.map(element=>{
    var count=0;
    arr1.forEach(function(i){
         if(i<=element)
            count++;
    });
    return count;
   });
  alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach by sorting both arrays first (or a copy) and then take a closure over an index variable and map the last found index (plus one) to the corresponding search value.

The result is actually a sorted array of counts for using with a `Map`. Then return the mapped indices.

```js
function fn(a, b) {
    const
        ASC = (a, b) => a - b;

    var indices;

    a.sort(ASC);
    indices = new Map(
        b.slice().sort(ASC).map((i => v => {
            while (i in a && a[i] <= v) ++i;
            return [v, i];
        })(0))
    );
    return b.map(v => indices.get(v));
}

console.log(fn([1, 2, 3], [2, 4]));
```